# Finding the Integral of A Composition of Logarithm, exp, and Trigometric Functions

Tags: integration, function-and-relation-composition

I have the function $$f(x)=\ln \left(e^{5+6\left(\sum_{k=0}^{100} \frac{\sin \left(k\pi x\right)}k \right)}+e \right)$$
One, is it possible to integrate this without "special functions" (functions like $|x|$ are OK, but not functions like $\mathbb{erf}(x)$)? If so, how? If not, why?

Comment: what is the integral?

Comment: @NinadMunshi No, I want to find the integral of $f$.

Comment: No, I mean can you write the integral you want to find in the question (bounds, etc)

Comment: He wants $\int f(x)dx$; I feel like the question is perfectly clear in that respect.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yeah, I just want to find the indefinite integral.

Comment: oh ok sounds good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to have a closed form expression of
$$I_p=\int \log\Big[e+\exp\left(5+6\sum_{k=0}^p \frac{\sin (\pi  k x)}{k} \right) \Big]\,dx$$

$$I_0=\int\log \left(e+e^{5+6 \pi  x}\right)\,dx=x-\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(-e^{6 \pi  x+4}\right)}{6 \pi }$$ where already appears a special function.

$$I_1=\int\log \left(e+e^{5+6 (\pi  x+\sin (\pi  x))}\right)\,dx$$ does not show any antiderivative.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! +1 and accepted! Though, I have to ask, how did you solve it? I tried using Mathematica and it timed out.

Comment: @DUO. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral+of+Log%5BE+%2B+E%5E%285+%2B+6*Pi*x%29%5D

Comment: Umm, part of the link cut out.

Comment: Then type **Integral of Log[E + E^(5 + 6*Pi*x)]**

Comment: OK. Thank you again!